# building program with make and automatic dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile

I have written a simple C++ program, and for the first time I want to compile and link it using a `makefile`. As a challenge I want to make a makefile, which lists all dependencies by itself. I am following [this](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-2-SECT-7) tutorial. My program consist of `main.cpp`, `ext1.cpp` and `ext1.h`. Following the tutorial, I have the following makefile

```
VPATH    = src include

CPPFLAGS = -o include

CC = gcc

SOURCES  = main.cpp \
       ext1.cpp



-include $(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES))



%.d: %.c
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
```

When I run this I get the message: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.` It is not clear to me what I am missing in my case?

Comment: The actions must be prefixed with a TAB. Spaces will not work. Could that be it?

Comment: @suspectus Thanks for the suggestion -- I made sure they were all TABs before testing

Comment: Without going into much details, your source files are `.cpp`, but you are trying to use `.c` dependencies...

Comment: @PetrBudnik Do you know how I can fix this? I feel pretty stuck

Comment: Simply put - the guide you are trying to follow uses `.c` files as sources. And dances around this fact. For example, `%.d: %.c` looks for `.c` files, not `.cpp`. But you have `.cpp`, no `.c` sources. Change `.c` to `.cpp` everywhere... And also, I assume you are familiar with regex since you are using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do too much at once.

**Step 1.** Your first makefile should build the executable *without* attempting automatic dependency detection.

```
VPATH = include src
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude
CC = gcc

exec: main.o ext1.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o ext1.o: ext1.h
```

**Step 2.** Once that works perfectly, you can put the header dependencies in separate files:

makefile:

```
VPATH = include src
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude
CC = gcc

exec: main.o ext1.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

-include *.d
```

main.d:

```
main.o : ext1.h
```

ext1.d:

```
ext1.o: ext1.h
```

**Step 3.** Once *that* works perfectly, you can generate the dependency files automatically:

```
VPATH = include src
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude
CC = gcc

exec: main.o ext1.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) -c -MMD $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@

-include *.d
```

Answer (score 1):

no make file found ? what name you have given for makefile? make sure its `makefile` or `Makefile` if you are just executing command `make` else you can pass file name to `make` like this

```
make -f yourmakefile
```

and changes suggested by  Petr Budnik must work